# Use elements of vector as inputs for function of multiple arguments

Tags: r

This should be simple but I can't figure it out. Suppose I have a function with *n* arguments, say:

```
example <- function(a, b, c){a*b + c}
```

I also have a vector `x` of length *n* and want to use that as an input for the function, that is: I want to evaluate

```
example(x[1], x[2], x[3])
```

Of course typing this is not so bad for *n = 3* but it becomes annoying from *n = 5* onwards. So ideally I would just type

```
example(x)
```

and have R understand what I mean, but that doesn't work. (It will tell me `argument b missing with no default`, apparently taking all of `x` to be `a` and then having nothing left to work with.)

So is there some trick to do this, e.g. by automatically generating the code `"a = x[1]; b = x[2]; c = x[3]"` and then magically having this unquoted and evaluated inside `example` before the rest of the definition?

Comment: Nice question but `do.call(example, as.list(x))`.

Comment: @Jimbou Sorry but what colnames?

Comment: It might be that there is something missing in your question or for example `example <- function(x) {x[1] * x[2] + x[3]}; example(c(2, 4, 1))`.

Comment: @r.user.05apr Well, yes this example is extremely small, but suppose that either a) I wrote function example but it involves 1.000.000 instances of terms that would look like `x[i]` and I (not thinking far enough ahead) thought I could save typing 3.000.000 characters by just calling them a, b, c etc instead; or that b) someone else wrote example and I don't trust my own understanding of the inner workings of the function enough to modify it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes that works! If you write it as an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with `do.call`. But you must coerce the function's argument (`do.call`'s second argument) to `list`.

```
example <- function(a, b, c){a*b + c}

x <- 1:3
do.call(example, as.list(x))
#[1] 5
```

However, note that this will fail if the vector is too short or too long:

```
y <- 1:4
do.call(example, as.list(y))
#Error in (function (a, b, c)  : unused argument (4)
```